# Using random values obtained from the global random number generator in Haskell in arithmetic and logic operations

Tags: haskell, random, monads

How do you use `IO Double` values obtained from the global random number generator in Haskell in arithmetic and logic operations? Most tutorials on the internet focus on obtaining random numbers, but somehow I seem not to be able to do something useful with them.

The following code contains some function `test` containing some of the operations I want to perform.

```
{-# LANGUAGE Strict #-}
module RNG where
import System.Random(setStdGen, mkStdGen, randomRIO)

seed_rng :: Int -> IO()
seed_rng seed = (setStdGen (mkStdGen seed))

uniform_float :: IO Double
uniform_float = (randomRIO (0.0, 1.0))

test :: Double -> Double -> IO Double
test a b = let u = (uniform_float)
              in if ((<) (return a) u) then ((+) (return b) u) else (return 2.0)
```

The test function does not compile since there is no instance for `Ord (IO Double)` and `Num (IO Double)`.

Note that I can avoid the `IO Monad` by implementing a random number generator and tracking+passing the state myself. But I rather learn to work with `Monads` instead of always trying to run away from them.

Comment: Tangential question: is there any specific reason why you are using `{-# LANGUAGE Strict #-}`?

Comment: @duplode Very performance critical code (practically only number crushing). I actually never need the pros of lazy evaluation.

Comment: Okay, that sounds reasonable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a monadic context, you can use `do` to actually run the computation:

```
test :: Double -> Double -> IO Double
test a b = do
   u <- uniform_float
   if a < u
      then return (b + u)
      else return 2.0
```

The general idea is: use `<-` to temporarily extract a `Double` from a `IO Double`, and then put the result back inside `IO` using `return`.

For instance, this sums two uniform numbers:

```
sumTwo :: IO Double
sumTwo = do
   x <- uniform_float
   y <- uniform_float
   return (x+y)
```

There are alternatives to `do`, but I'd recommend learning `do` first, since it's reasonably general and simple enough. When you get more accustomed to monadic computations, applicatives and functors, you'll probably also like compact alternatives like `sumTwo = (+) <$> uniform_float <*> uniform_float`.

Answer (score 3):

`(>>=)` can be used to chain a second monadic computation that uses the `Double` values.

```
test :: Double -> Double -> IO Double
test a b = uniform_float >>= \u -> return (if a < u then b + u else 2.0)
```

An alternative way of writing the above is using a do-block:

```
test :: Double -> Double -> IO Double
test a b = do
    u <- uniform_float
    return (if a < u then b + u else 2.0)
```

Finally, in cases like this one, in which the second monadic computation is simply a non-monadic computation followed by a `return`, you don't even need `(>>=)` -- `fmap` is enough:

```
test :: Double -> Double -> IO Double
test a b = fmap (\u -> if a < u then b + u else 2.0) uniform_float
```